# is there any ros2 rep like rqt_configure in ros1?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

besides， dynamic_reconfigure is also needed , any one can tell me about it ? or there is some rep work same to it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301923/is-there-any-ros2-rep-like-rqt_configure-in-ros1-?/) by [lxbeyond](https://answers.ros.org/users/36253/lxbeyond/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-08-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS 2 doesn't have / need `dynamic_reconfigure`. The functionality has been integrated into the parameter subsystem (see the corresponding [design article](http://design.ros2.org/articles/ros_parameters.html)).

`rqt` has not been ported to ROS 2 at this time.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lxbeyond](https://answers.ros.org/users/36253/lxbeyond/) on 2018-08-29**:
will rqt be ported in the future ? and when ?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-29**:
Yes, as soon as someone has time to work on it...

**Comment by [lxbeyond](https://answers.ros.org/users/36253/lxbeyond/) on 2018-08-29**:
as I know, parameter subsystem of python lacks some function as to c++, and it seems to not be able to support dynamic_reconfigure.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-30**:
Parameter support in `rclpy` has just recently been merged so you will need to build from master to use it. I have no idea what you mean with "it seems to not be able to support dynamic_reconfigure"?